# CAML Query to select top level folders only

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I want to select the list of folders (without subfolders, not recursive) of a Document library using CrossListQueryCache.

Everything is working fine except that i am receiving ALL the folders and subfolders in the list and not just the first level of folders. 
what do i need to change in the code below so that only the first level of folders is returned without their subfolders and sub-subfolders etc...

```
string query = string.Empty;
string websQuery = string.Format("<Webs Scope=\"{0}\"/>", "None");
string lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"101\"" + " ><List ID=\"" + listid + "\" /></Lists>";  
bool useList = true;
string relativeUrl = this.GetRelativeUrl();
query = string.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='LookUp'>1</Value></Eq></Where>", relativeUrl); 

CrossListQueryInfo info = new CrossListQueryInfo();
info.Lists = lists;
info.Webs = websQuery;
info.Query = query;
info.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\"/>";
info.WebUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl;
CrossListQueryCache cache = new CrossListQueryCache(info);
SiteDataResults sd = cache.GetSiteDataResults(site, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SPQuery.ViewAttributes with "Scope" different from "Recursive":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewattributes.aspx

If you want to display only folders or NOT folders then you can add info about ContentType, like here (Drax's answer):
[CAML queries: how to filter folders from result set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333328/caml-queries-how-to-filter-folders-from-result-set)